# HTML image map incorrectly maps for some users but not others

Tags: html, email, dictionary, imagemap

Okay, I have an email I have created where The images use maps to redirect to different links. The email works fine from my email and one other's email, but another person has the links for the bottom image not mapping correctly.

```
<img src="https://example.com/images/NPHomeButtons.jpg" usemap= #HomeButtons border=0 width=600>
<map name=HomeButtons>
<area shape=Rect Coords=0,0,120,48 Href="http://www.example.com/">
<area shape=Rect Coords=120,0,240,48 Href="http://www.example.com/inventory/New/">
<area shape=Rect Coords=240,0,360,48 Href="http://www.example.com/inventory/Used/">
<area shape=Rect Coords=360,0,480,48 Href="http://www.example.com/get-approved/">
<area shape=Rect Coords=480,0,600,48 Href="http://www.example.com/contact-us/">
</map>
```

But on this image, the other user is having issues

```
<img src="https://example.com/images/NPAdGraphic.jpg" usemap= #AdGraphic border=0>
<map name="AdGraphic" id="AdGraphic">
<area  alt="" title="" href="http://www.example.com/giveaway/" shape="rect" coords="0,5,600,182" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="" href="http://www.example.com/giveaway/" shape="rect" coords="9,1205,224,1278" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="" href="http://www.example.com/inventory/New/Mazda/" shape="rect" coords="231,1206,451,1277" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
</map>
```

On the other user's site the two last areas are mapped an image higher than they should be

We all tried opening the image in browsers and in outlook, but I could not replicate his issue nor could we find a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be missing several `"`s in your first block of code.

Comment: I didn't use it the first time, however it still works perfectly fine

Comment: "It works" is not a valid reason for writing bad code. For example, this is functional JavaScript: `!function(e){location="http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q="+(e[0]?e.reduce(function(e,n){return e+(~n.indexOf("-")?"-%5B"+n.substring(1):"%5B"+n)+"%5D+"},""):e)+"created%3A..60d+‌​answers%3A0+closed%3Ano"}(prompt("Tags: (leave blank for none)").trim().split(/\s+/))` but I would _never_ use that anywhere I could avoid it.

Comment: When I fist learned mapping, the site I learned it from did not use `"` in their code, which is why I did not use it there. Either way, it does not detract from the fact that the new code is the one going haywire

Comment: ...Hmm, maybe I don't know quite as much about HTML as I thought. It certainly seems to be standard, though. (And yeah, I know that the first works; I just like pointing out little improvements you can make)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the main difference is that the first image has width and the second no, have you tried adding width to the second image ?

Comment: If you want to ask for clarification, wait until you've earned the privilege of posting a comment, rather than writing your comment in a text box with "**Your Answer**" in big, bold letters